# Как сравнить дату и textbox?

Tags: c++-cli, ms-access

Есть база данных, в которой в формате даты хранятся даты. В `textBox3` записывается дата, надо выбрать из этой базы данных только те записи, дата которых больше чем та, что в `textbox`.

```
//поиск по дате
System::Void kurs::Forma::button3_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    dataGridView1->Rows->Clear();
    //Подключение к бд
    String^ connectionString = "provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=data.mdb";
    OleDbConnection^ dbConnection = gcnew OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    //Выполнение запроса к БД
    dbConnection->Open();
    String^ query = "SELECT code, theme, data, city FROM [conference] WHERE data > '" + textBox3 + "'";
    OleDbCommand^ dbComand = gcnew OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);
    OleDbDataReader^ dbReader = dbComand->ExecuteReader();

    //Проверяем данные
    if (dbReader->HasRows == false) {
        MessageBox::Show("Ничего не найдено!", "Ошибка!");
    }
    else {
        while (dbReader->Read()) {
            dataGridView1->Rows->Add(dbReader["code"], dbReader["theme"], dbReader["data"], dbReader["city"]);
        }
    }

    textBox3->Clear();

    return System::Void();
}
```

Ошибка в этой строке и я не понимаю, как её исправить.

```
String^ query = "SELECT code, theme, data, city FROM [conference] WHERE data > '" + textBox3 + "'";
```

Comment: в бд у data формат дата и время. если написать WHERE data > Date(); то выполнится и выведет только те записи, что после сегодняшнего числа

Comment: если выполнить код, то после нажатия кнопки выдаёт:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."

Comment: ```+ textBox3->Text +``` вот так к тексту обратиться в текстбоксе

Comment: все равно пишет "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."

Comment: String^ query = "SELECT code, theme, data, city FROM [conference] WHERE data > @textDate"; OleDbCommand^ dbComand = gcnew OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection); dbComand->Parameters->Add("@textDate", System::Data::OleDbType::Date)->Value = DateTime::Parse(textBox3->Text); OleDbDataReader^ dbReader = dbComand->ExecuteReader();